# XAML StringFormat syntax for decimal places

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF screen and a TextBox field which should display a calculated percentage value (which is a double). The value is already correct i.e. it is 21 for 21% (therefore does not need to be multiplied by 100) but it has decimal places and I need to add the % symbol.

I do not wish to round in the C# code as I lose my precision which is required in other calculations. I simply wish to use StringFormat in the XAML to put a format mask on the number. So 21.333 should be seen on screen as 21%.

This is what works so far to truncate off the decimal places but no matter the configuration I try I cannot seem to add the % symbol as well.

```
Text="{Binding Brokerage, StringFormat='0,0.'}"
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the fixed-point [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) with zero decimal places, `F0`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Brokerage, StringFormat={}{0:F0}%}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

{Binding OrderQTY, StringFormat={0:0.##}}

Answer (score 2):

Your string format should be in the form of

```
 "{Binding Path=Percentage, StringFormat={}{0}%}"
```

Comment: Alas I have tried this already and it leaves the decimal places. Thanks for answering though @TYY.